# Thread subprocess excecutables loop

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, subprocess, exe

I would like to run several Excecutables with different parameters in parallel.
I have looked at various issues regarding threadding and subprocessing. However, I am not getting anywhere.
Here is an example how I would like to call the excecutables. But instead of processing them one after the other I would like to call them in parallel to save CPU time:

```
while (i<=anzahl):
    subprocess.run(["a.exe", mat[i][1], mat[i][2], mat[i][3], mat[i][4], mat[i][5], mat[i][0]], shell=True)
    i = i+1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run multiple subprocesses in parallel and wait for them to finish in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686295/how-do-i-run-multiple-subprocesses-in-parallel-and-wait-for-them-to-finish-in-py)

Comment: yeah looks like. Thank you very much :)